# NTopng - Unable to start HTTP server on port 3000 - Can't login to web gui

Tags: ntop, login

I can access NTop via IP:3000 though the default login/pass doesn't go anywhere, just a refresh.

And when running "ntopng -v -G /var/run/ntopng.pid -i 1 -s" I get:

> [HTTPserver.cpp:350] HTTPS Disabled: missing SSL certificate ? /usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/ssl/ntopng-cert.pem
>
> 11:36:50 [HTTPserver.cpp:351] Please read README.SSL if you want to enable SSL
>
> 11:36:50 [HTTPserver.cpp:371] ERROR: Unable to start HTTP server (IPv4) on port 3000

I do have a webserver installed and running on the server itself and iptables are off for now.
I followed this guide for installation: http://blog.redbranch.net/2013/11/07/ntopng-on-centos-6/

Answer (score 1):

This is a common problem, it happens when the port 3000 isn't free/open.

An easy fix is for you to change the port to a free one, 3050 perhaps by changing the ntopng.conf file in /etc/ntopng/ntopng.conf.

Add the line "-w=3050"(i.e if you choose to use port 3050).

Restart ntopng, all should be well.

Comment: sudo ntopng -w :3050 -i eth0

Answer (score 0):

I also had the problem. This is how I solved it:

Using other ports than 3000 didn't work.

I then followed the instructions in the README.SSL and created an SSL certificate. That done, the warnings about the SSL disappeared but

> [HTTPserver.cpp:371] ERROR: Unable to start HTTP server (IPv4) on port 3000

remained. After long googling I found this: http://ntop.unipi.narkive.com/7c9xgPAQ/ssl-public-trusted-certificate.
The symbolic link for the certificate must point to 
`ln -s /usr/lib/libssl.so` 
in certain distributions, and openssl-devel must be installed.

After that, ntopng started but I still couldn't log in on the web interface, which was resolved by clearing the browser cache.